# Dynamic error pages in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, error-handling, actionview

In Rails 2.3.x, you can override `render_optional_error_file` like so:

```
# ApplicationController.rb
protected
  def render_optional_error_file(status_code)
    render :template => "errors/500", :status => 500, :layout => 'application'
  end
```

However, Rails 3 no longer has `render_optional_error_file`. Instead, you need to override `rescue_action_in_public`, which you can do like so:

```
# config/initializers/error_page.rb
module ActionDispatch
  class ShowExceptions

    protected    
      def rescue_action_in_public(exception)
        status = status_code(exception).to_s

        template = ActionView::Base.new(["#{Rails.root}/app/views"])
        if ["404"].include?(status)
          file = "/errors/404.html.erb"
        else
          file = "/errors/500.html.erb"
        end        
        body = template.render(:file => file)

        render(status, body)
      end

  end
end
```

This works, but does not use the application's layout. However, if you specify the layout path like so:

```
body = template.render(:file => file, :layout => "layouts/application") # line 15
```

You get an `Error during failsafe response: ActionView::Template::Error`.

Line 4 of application.html.erb:4 is:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "app", "jquery-ui", "jquery.fancybox", :cache => "all" %>
```

Whatever ActionView normally uses to render templates isn't getting loaded.

The stack trace is:

```
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:794:in `join'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:794:in `rails_asset_id'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:817:in `rewrite_asset_path'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:746:in `compute_public_path'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:424:in `path_to_stylesheet'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:875:in `ensure_stylesheet_sources!'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:874:in `each'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:874:in `ensure_stylesheet_sources!'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:512:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
  /data/sites/fundraisers-stage/releases/20110316194843/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___19482063_70294907435920_0'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `send'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `render'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/render/layouts.rb:80:in `_render_layout'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:62:in `_render_template'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
  /data/sites/fundraisers-stage/releases/20110316194843/config/initializers/error_pages.rb:15:in `rescue_action_in_public'
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In rails 3.2, it's easier than that:

Add this to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

That causes errors to be routed via the router.  Then you just add to `config/routes.rb`:

```
match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found"
```

I got this info from item #3 on the blog post "[My five favorite hidden features in Rails 3.2](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/)" by By José Valim.

Comment: The `config.exceptions_app = self.routes` works for the 404 error, but  it also keeps the 500 error from loading the 500.html file. Is it possible to set the 404 to be loaded from the app but keep the 500 error loading from the static file? (Because if something is broken in the app, it might cause the error message to also break.) Thanks!

Comment: In response to my comment, this post might help: http://ariejan.net/2011/10/14/rails-3-customized-exception-handling

Comment: Here's a great post on handling custom exceptions: http://geekmonkey.org/articles/29-exception-applications-in-rails-3-2

Comment: Here's sample implmentation: https://github.com/sheerun/rails4-bootstrap/issues/26

Comment: You should also handle 500 and 422 errors as well:
`%w(404 422 500).each { |code| get code, to: "errors#show", code: code }`
and in ErrorsController show method: `@status = params[:code] || 500` `render @status`

Answer (score 51):

I would suggest using **rescue_from** instead. You would just rescue from specific errors rather than overriding rescue_action_in_public. This is especially useful when dealing with user-defined errors or controller-specific errors.

```
# ApplicationController
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_404
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, :with => :render_404
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404
rescue_from MyApp::CustomError, :with => :custom_error_resolution

def render_404
  if /(jpe?g|png|gif)/i === request.path
    render :text => "404 Not Found", :status => 404
  else
    render :template => "shared/404", :layout => 'application', :status => 404
  end
end

# UsersController
rescue_from MyApp::SomeReallySpecificUserError, :with => :user_controller_resolution
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html

Comment: The problem with using `rescue_from` is that it halts the error chain. I don't want the error chain to be halted; I want it to continue to propagate. That way, `exception_notifier` will still work.

Comment: Gotcha; I use hoptoad so I usually end up doing a 'rescue_from Exception' as a catch-all, notify hoptoad with the error, then execute some dynamic error handling. Can you try... render(:template => file, :layout => '/layouts/application', :status => 404) and see if that works?

Comment: That makes no difference — same backtrace as before. I need to find some way to have ActionView's context set up as it expects. Perhaps I can call its render function directly?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you make your code a module and include it in ApplicationController?

Comment: How would I do that? It's currently a module: `module ActionDispatch class ShowExceptions`.

Comment: I tried that, and 500 errors give me an empty response (`Content-Length: 0`).

Answer (score 3):

The exception notifier has a method called `notify_about_exception` to initiate the error notification on demand.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ExceptionNotification::Notifiable

  rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_all_errors

  def render_all_errors(e)
    log_error(e) # log the error
    notify_about_exception(e) # send the error notification

    # now handle the page
    if e.is_a?(ActionController::RoutingError)
      render_404(e)
    else
      render_other_error(e)
    end
  end

  def render_404_error(e)
   # your code
  end

  def render_other_error(e)
   # your code
  end
end
```

Comment: This is useful, but not general-purpose — it only works with a specific ExceptionNotifier, and fails if one's not installed. I'm using https://github.com/railsware/exception_notification. I suppose you could test for `defined?()`, but really, I just want to override the rendering code, not the whole stack.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced such problem. The problem is because of attachment_fu gem or plugin. Just uninstall it and use any other plugin or gem will solve your problem.