# rails 410 on no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When someone goes to my site with wrong route, rails responses with `404` code and the error

`ActionController::RoutingError No route matches`

Can I response with `410` code on the rails's error instead of `404`?

Comment: 404 would be for an incorrect url. 410 would be for deleted content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to as a [410 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_error_codes#4xx_Client_Error) (Gone) is for a resource that was once available but isn't anymore.

If you follow the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5360684/219743 then it allows you to do it.

Just change the render_404 method to

```
def render_404
  if /(jpe?g|png|gif)/i === request.path
    render :text => "404 Not Found", :status => 410 # Change the status here
  else
    render :template => "shared/404", :layout => 'application', :status => 410 #and here
  end
end
```

If you still want to point to 404.html in the public folder:

```
render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html"
```