# Rails production 404,500 etc error pages with same layout as rest webpages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How could i render my error pages in production mode, so that they are in same layout as rest pages? For example, not 404 as standart

```
<h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>
    <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>
```

without any layout, but this message in my layout (called application.html.haml)?

Is it real? And what and where i need to write? I google'd but for own layout didn't find good one....

i use rails 3.2.8, ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Here's what Google gave me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11051883/648392

Comment: @Jesper i see that, but! how to set my layout? there i see only routing tot 404.html i'm new, i need normal and full manual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be this:

```
# In config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes

# In routes
match "/404", to: "errors#not_found"
match "/500", to: "errors#server_error"

# app/controllers/errors_controller.rb

class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  # Inherits layout from ApplicationController 

  def not_found
  end

  def server_error
  end
end

# app/views/errors/not_found.haml
%h1 Didn't find nothing!

# app/views/errors/server_error.haml
%h1 FUBAR!
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. But there is a missing piece:

`# app/config/environments/development.rb`
`config.consider_all_requests_local       = false`

Comment: It's also worth noting that the returned status code will be changed to '200' unless you explicitly set it on your controller. A simple `render status: 404` will do.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method, you should find the same for Rails 3

http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/07/rails-404/